# lost local commit when checking out a remote branch

Tags: git, git-extensions

I checked out the master branch, and did some changes. Then I committed my changes on the master branch but did not push it to repository.

What I did next is check out the remote master again. Then could not see my local commit anymore.

How could I get my local commit back?

Comment: what's the output of `git branch -vvv`?

Comment: This is the output: master    f535210 [origin/master] added a seq diagram

Comment: Then you probably lost your commits because you overwrote your local master with remote. Maybe you still have the old commits (git does not always do garbage collection immediately) but I'm not sure how you can check or use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reset the `HEAD`. Use the following to revert to the previous commit.

```
git reflog
```

This will give the list of all the commits with head values. Choose the `HEAD` for the commit you made to the local master branch.

Then, do the following,

```
git reset --hard HEAD@<i>
```

Comment: e.g. `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}` (or {3}, or {4}, or whichever you want to reset to)